# Anonymous access for Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, anonymous-access

I have a Custom List which is named as "Enquiry". I required to **set the List to anonymous access** for my SharePoint Online 2013 Public facing site.

*Can any one help me to achieve this?*

Comment: Where is the list Enquiry situated? In a private site collection? Currently it's not possible to exchange information between the public facing site and the private site collections.

Comment: Hi ,The list is in Public Facing site

Answer (score 0):

To configure an list or library for anonymous access steps are

1. Navigate to a list or library that the app for SharePoint that you
   are testing accesses and open the List Settings or Library Settings.
   For a SharePoint Online site, you must be logged in as a tenant
   administrator.
2. Choose Permissions for this list/library.
3. On the page that opens, choose Stop Inheriting Permissions on the
   Permissions tab, and then choose OK on the confirmation prompt.
4. Choose Anonymous Access on the Permission tab.
5. On the Anonymous Access form that opens, select all of the
   permissions that that users of the app for SharePoint require. You
   can grant permission to View, Edit, Add, and Delete items. You
   cannot grant Full Control, so anonymous users cannot change the
   schema of the list or change list settings.